# Library QUIRC is not linked. No decoding is performed. Take it to the OpenCV repository

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to get a qrcode with opencv, in order to do this I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

...

data, bbox,rectifiedImage = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(frame)

...
```

The code runs ok, but when detect the QRCode and I want get data, I got this

> Library QUIRC is not linked. No decoding is performed. Take it to the OpenCV repository.

I tried with `pip install quirc`, but doesn't work and I installed opencv with `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: don't install opencv via apt. the package will be many years old. -- install OpenCV via `pip3 install opencv-python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of OpenCV you get with the `apt` package is always fairly old. Additionally, there's no guarantee that all the modules (here: the QR decoder) were given the required dependencies (here: quirc). Installing additional packages wouldn't solve this because OpenCV needs them at build time, before packaging.

To get the most recent version, install it via *pip*:

```
$ pip3 install opencv-python
```

There is the `opencv-python` package that only contains the main modules, and there is `opencv-contrib-python`, which *additionally* contains "contrib" modules. The packages are mutually incompatible, so only install one of them.